# Python: Comparing a date to a date within list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, datetime, dictionary, search

I have a (large) list of dictionaires, containing tasks and their metadata extracted from Wunderlist. The name of the list is `tasktotal`. These dictionaries within the list look like this:

```
{'due_date': '2016-11-30', 'created_by_request_id': 'RqID:RqIDKey', 'type': 'task', 'title': 'This is a task ', 'completed': False, 'id': MYID, 'created_by_id': MYID, 'created_at': '2016-10-14T11:11:52.916Z', 'revision': 2, 'starred': False, 'list_id': MYLISTID}
```

I would like to compare the 'due_date' value to the current date using `datetime`:

```
date_today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

If the dictinary is due today or any day before today, I would like to return the 'title' value from this dictionary. I figured that the easiest way would be to create a new dictionary with all the entries that are due today, and then retrieve their 'title' values. So I made this search function:

```
def search(i):
    return [element for element in i if element[datetime.strptime('due_date')] >= date_today]
```

However, when I run this search on my `tasktotal` list, I get nothing returned.

```
print(search(tasktotal))

[]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here? Or is there maybe another more efficient way of retrieving the values that I need?

**EDIT 1:**

When I try the solution by @Peter, I get this error:

```
    return [element['title'] for element in i if date_convert(element['due_date']) >= current_time]
   KeyError: 'due_date
```

**EDIT 2:**
When I switch my brackets, like @James K and @RichSmith suggested, I get this error

```
    return [element for element in i if datetime.strptime(element['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d") >= date_today]
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

Comment: You may want to reply directly to each answer with specific messages for that answer.

Comment: Sorry, quite new around here, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The bracketing is wrong for

```
element[datetime.strptime('due_date')]
```

This tries to convert the string "due_date" to a time, and then look up that in the dictionary. Instead you need to lookup the date, then convert it.

```
datetime.strptime(element['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Comment: Of course! But still, the same error as #Peter:     return [element for element in i if datetime.strptime(element['due_date'], "%Y-%m-%d") >= date_today]
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: Answer forgot one of the arguments, but you fixed that. To fix the type, notice that datetime.strptime returns a datetime, which you can't directly compare to a date.  But you can convert it to a date first by calling .date()

Comment: Incorporated into the answer.

Comment: This code returns a key error for me: **KeyError: 'due_date'** I realised that this is very hard to recreate without any data, so I generated a test dictionary and put it in an online IDE over repl.it. Link is over here: [link](https://repl.it/EOFm/10). I also included both methodes described here, you can edit this code freely online or copy it into your own IDE of course.

Comment: The KeyError is the same as all the other answers.  Your question said the data had that key, oops it doesn't, so just check for 'due_date' in element or use element.get('due_date')

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of titles returned, you can just use `element['title']`.

I've not really used datetime so quickly threw together a slightly different solution, it converts the date to its timestamp so you can adjust the format if needed. To me at least, since it's comparing the numbers themselves instead of relying on `datetime` to do the comparison, it seems a bit more robust.

I did a quick test and this is roughly 20-25% slower, it takes 1.25 seconds per 6k values as opposed to 1 though, so it's not too noticeable.

```
import datetime
import time

def date_convert(due_date):
    return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(due_date, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

def search(i):
    current_time = 86400 * int(time.time() / 86400)
    future_date = '3000-01-01'
    return [element['title'] for element in i if date_convert(element.get('due_date', future_date)) <= current_time]
```

For the record, the `86400` which pops up is just to get the current time in seconds rounded to the start of the day, since that's the highest accuracy the data uses.

Comment: I like it! But now I have a different error:     return [element['title'] for element in i if date_convert(element['due_date']) >= current_time]
KeyError: 'due_date

Comment: @kenny Ostrom This may be true, the dictionaries are extracted from a Wunderlist account. Not all task here have due dates, so not every dictionary has the 'due_date' element. Is this the issue with this approach?

Comment: This works for the data you gave, but not in your real data, because your real data is different.  I suggest that instead of element['due_date'] you use element.get('due_date', default). Or you can just ignore the bad entries by checking if 'due_date' in element and ...  -- sorry I deleted my comment to rewrite a better one.

Comment: Thanks, updated with Kenny's suggestion, I didn't realise some records might not have had `due_date` :)   I'm guessing you don't want those records returned, however if you do, just change `invalid_date` to something in the past.

Comment: I'm very sorry but this still doesn't return any values. I realised that this is very hard to recreate without any data, so I generated a test dictionary and put it in an online IDE over repl.it. Link is over here: [link](https://repl.it/EOFm/10). I also included both methodes described here, you can edit this code freely online or copy it into your own IDE of course.

Comment: Oops, I missed an equals haha, it was supposed to be `current_time *= 86400`. I copied your `tasktotal` and it seems to work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move your strptime.

try:

```
def search(i):
    return [element for element in i if datetime.strptime(element["due_date"]) >= date_today]
```

that way the `element["due_date"]` will fetch the date in each of your dictionaries.

Comment: You forgot one of the arguments